# How to simplify fractional powers in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I was wondering how to make Mathematica simplify (x^2(y^2+1))^(5/2)*(y^2+1)^(3/2) to x^5(y^2+1)^4?

[Simplify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHq12.png)

[FullSimplify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DWRA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FullSimplify[<expression>]`](http://mathematica%20fullsiplify) to cause Mathematica to attempt to simplify your expression using a variety of strategies.  You might need to include some of your assumptions about `x` and `y` to get the result you expect.  For example, are `x` and `y` both real numbers?  Then you could try:

```
FullSimplify[(x^2(y^2+1))^(5/2)*(y^2+1)^(3/2), {Element[{x,y},Reals]}]
```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work.See the above edit in the question.

Comment: Yes, x and y are real numbers. and x is positive.

Comment: I am sorry how to get rid of Abs[x] if x is positive? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can include, e.g. `x > 0` in your assumptions, like `FullSimplify[<whatever>, {Element[y, Reals], x > 0}]`.  I don't have Mathematica in front of me right now, but that's the general idea.

Comment: I get rid of Abs by using /.{Abs[x]->x} at the end of the expression, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `/.{Abs[x]->x}` just tells Mathematica to blindly make that substitution at the end.  If you want to get Mathematica to not produce the `Abs[x]` in the first place you need to make sure Mathematica understands that `x` is a positive real to begin with.  I feel like including `x > 0` in the assumptions for `FullSimplify` should do the trick, but like I said I don't have it in front of me to verify at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
(x^2 (y^2 + 1))^(5/2)*(y^2 + 1)^(3/2) // Assuming[Element[{x,y},Reals], Simplify[#]] &
```

Out:

```
(1 + y^2)^4 Abs[x]^5
```